# opencv aruco module crashes on AMD processors, but runs on Intel processors

Tags: opencv, amd-processor, aruco

I have a function in my application that uses opencv and the `cv::aruco` module.

On machines with Intel cpus, it runs great. (tested on more than 20 PCs). On machines with AMD cpus (tested on two), it freezes and crashes the application. The only difference on the testing machines is the processor.

I have tried rebuilding opencv and disabling AVX512 instructions, and I see the same thing.

Why might this be happening?

The specific function that crashes is:

```
cv::aruco::detectMarkers(InImage, dictionary5, corners, ids, detectorParams5, rejected);
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: I have no idea what the cause is, but if it helps, I have run `detectMarkers` function in both Ryzen 5 1600 and Ryzen 7 1700x CPUs without any issues (both in Linux). Are you using Windows?

Comment: Yes, this is on Windows. Opencv was built on an I7 processor, and crashes on any Ryzen processor.